# How to remove character in pandas column from specific index if character exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas column where I would like to remove the last character if character equals to 'F'.

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`pandas.Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['test', 'test_f', 'test_F']
})

df['res'] = np.where(df['col'].str.endswith('F'), df['col'].str[:-1], df['col'])
```

```
    col     res
0   test    test
1   test_f  test_f
2   test_F  test_
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `str.replace`

```
df['col'].str.replace('F$', '')
                      # |
                      # Ensures it's the last

#0    Foo
#1    bar
#2     oF
#3      O
#4    tof
#Name: col, dtype: object
```

Add `case=False` as an argument if you want to remove both the last `'F'` or `'f'`

---

Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['Foo', 'bar', 'oFF', 'OF', 'tof']})
```